# Issues with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have

Gemset ---->

```
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'.
```

application.css ---- >

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
```

application.js ---->

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require_directory ./vendor
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require_directory ./vendor
```

application.html.erb ---->

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

and i am getting an error like "**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'** ", in the browser console , Could any one please help me out

Comment: Post the application.js content here.

Comment: @sidhu for the future, it would be better to post that source in your question.

Comment: Please pick a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , i find out the solution. When we install jquery using

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

We should not include any other jquery files in our application. When i deleted those files and run the application , issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason could be that you have already require jquery.ui.all which also has a js for autocomplete widget. So, you can remove the last //= require jquery.ui.autocomplete and it should fix the problem.